# Yii2 : view file and wbraganca dynamic forms

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using [wbraganca dynamic forms](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform). I have these codes in my controller :

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $rackObjects = RackObjects::find()->where(['rackID' => $id])->one();
    if (!$rackObjects) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Empty rack');
    }
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'rackObjects' => $rackObjects,
    ]);  
}
```

my view file :

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'rackID',
        'height',
        'width',
    ],
]) ?>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
<h3>Objects in <?= $this->title ?></h3>
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $rackObjects,
    'attributes' => [
        'ObjectTitle',
        'objectID',
        'rack_unit',
        'Attached'
    ],
]) ?>
</div>
```

I want to have all my rackObjects in multiple detailview not only one detailview like this example : http://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions/dynamicform-demo1/view?id=721

how should I write the codes like example? There is no codes in demos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$rackObjects = RackObjects::find()->where(['rackID' => $id])->all();
```

probably as u have already tried **all()**,
i'd suggest a try in your view file along with querying **all()**

```
foreach ($rackObjects as $rackObject) {
   <?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $rackObject,
    'attributes' => [
        'ObjectTitle',
        'objectID',
        'rack_unit',
        'Attached'
    ],
]) ?>
}
```

what it does is, when you have queried all, you get an array of objects and you might want to loop your widget over each of the objects. and gives you multiple detailViews as you desire.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are returnig only one row, as you specify
 $rackObjects = RackObjects::find()->where(['rackID' => $id])**->one()**;
Replace that with **->all();**
Modify value of columns in you detail view if you want everything in one grid.

Answer (score 0):

Amir zaghari.

I'm newbie in YII2 and I use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;

I try to follow your step to show data in Detailview but I got an error.

```
Undefined variable: id
```

maybe I made something wrong. so can you explain how to coding in

```
public function actionView($id)
```

in controller.php
and

```
 DetailView::widget
```

to display data in _view.php

thank you, sir

Comment: Two videos that will help you :
[Dynamic Forms in Yii Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqFpTBr323Y&list=PLRd0zhQj3CBmusDbBzFgg3H20VxLx2mkF&index=28) , 
[Dynamic Forms in Yii Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAg0LIrZDdk&list=PLRd0zhQj3CBmusDbBzFgg3H20VxLx2mkF&index=29)